# mouseout effects on selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a product item that gets some effects when it is selected/deselected.
I do that via toggling on and off the *selected* class on click, like this:

```
$('.myItem').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected'); 
})
```

Now, I also need to apply a bunch of effects when the cursor leaves the item **while the item is selected.**

I tried to achieve this in many ways, but didn't succeed. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: `css` `.myItem:hover{ color:red}`

Comment: @0_o, should be `.myItem.selected:hover`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mouseleave for that, then you just have to check if the element has the class you want.

```
$('.myItem').mouseleave(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')
    {
        //Do effects
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Select the `.myItem` element that has class `.selected` and execute the function you want on `mouseleave`

```js
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.myItem.selected', function() {
  $(this).html('<h1 style="color:#fff;margin:0">Left from selected!</h1>');
});
$('.myItem').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected').empty();  
})
```

```css
.myItem {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
.myItem.selected { background-color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click to toggle class "selected"</p>
<div class="myItem"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add a check on the selected class, along with the mouseleave event.

Example:

```
$('.myItem').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$('.myItem').mouseleave(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        // do animation
        $(this).animate({
            fontSize: "+=10",
            left: "+=50"
        });
    }
});
```

Or the jQuery way of adding events:

```
$('.myItem').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$('.myItem').on('mouseleave', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        // do animation
        $(this).animate({
            fontSize: "+=10",
            left: "+=50"
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qn6zqqeh/1/